# 16 eighth notes in a 12/8 measure... How?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, time-signatures

[image]

Hello, I quite new to music theory. I was writing a code that reads through sheet music and noticed something I didn't understand in some of the measures (like in the image: the leftmost measure, top staff). The time signature is 12/8 but the measure has a total of the equivalent of 16 eighth notes. What does that mean and how does it happen? Please help.

The score is for a piano solo version of Lacrimosa

Comment: There's 2 voices.  Top voice is 8th rest - 8th - 8th (repeat repeat repeat) and the bottom voice is quarter - 8th rest (repeat repeat repeat), Both are 12 beats.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually miscounting, if you count the rests there are a total of 24 8th notes in that bar. The reason for that is that there are two independent voices, each with their own rests. @Edward mentioned this in his comment. Here is a slightly more detailed explanation:

There can be more than one voice, even several voices in one staff line. They are usually distinguished by stems in opposite directions. The bass clef is a single voice but the treble clef is two voices. Here is how they break down:

The top line (including the upper rests) is stems up. The pattern is 8th notes, rest-note-note (three 8th notes total) on each beat for all 4 beats.

The bottom line (including the lower rests) is stems down and is quarter note-8th rest (three 8th notes total) on each beat for all 4 beats.

The upper and lower lines add up to 12 each, thus 24 8th notes in the bar played by two separate voices.

Comment: While this is all true, it seems a bit confusing and/or semantically hair-splitting to lead with "there are 24," when the initial confusion is "why are there more than 12." To count 24, we're counting literal "eighth notes" (including rests) in all voices; when the OP counted 16 they were counting the passing of eighth-note durations throughout the meter, including during quarter notes; they just didn't know about voices. Might be nice to edit to lead with the current second paragraph?

Comment: @AndyBonner I purposely led with that to let the OP know that he  was correct in at least recognizing there are more then 12 8th notes but that rests must also be counted. My second sentence establishes the reason why.